# Can someone explain this to me? About reversible computing with finite energy and thermal equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

In [*Life, The Universe, and Nothing: Life and Death in an Ever-Expanding Universe*](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9902189), they examine the implications of dark energy on the ultimate fate of life.

Then they say this,

> It was long thought that computation is an entropy generating process, and thus a heat generating process. More recently [7, 8, 9] it has been pointed out that as long as (a) one is in contact with a heat bath, and (b) one is willing to compute arbitrarily slowly, then computing itself can be a reversible process. This opens the possibility that if living systems can alter their character so that consciousness can be reduced to computation, one could in principle reduce the amount of entropy, and hence the amount of heat produced per computation arbitrarily, if one is willing to take arbitrarily long to complete the computation. Thus, metabolism, and the continued existence of consciousness, could violate the DBSH. There are two problems. First, as we have shown, living things cannot remain in thermal equilibrium with the cosmic background forever, so inevitably the process of computation becomes irreversible.

Can someone explain this to me? Why would we want to be in thermal equilibrium with the cosmic background? Wouldn't that just mean that we're dead?

> This is because a cosmological constant dominated universe is permeated by background radiation at a constant temperature TdeS = $√ Λ/12π^2$."

Can't we use this background instead?

Comment: What does "DBSH" stand for ?

Comment: It stands for "Dyson's Biological Scaling Hypothesis". It's an idea discussed at the bottom of Page 13 of the paper linked.